# Api call throwing error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Quotes>'

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

here is my api call.

```
    class Httpservice {
    final Uri postURL = Uri.parse(
    "https://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire",
  );
 static dynamic quoteOfTheDay;

 Future<List<Quotes>> getQuotes() async {
 Response res = await get(postURL);

final jsonItems = json.decode(res.body)["contents"]["quotes"];
List<Quotes> quote = jsonItems.map<Quotes>((json) {
  return Quotes.fromJson(json);
}).toList();
quoteOfTheDay = quote;
return quote;
 }
}
```

This is the display page

```
    class PostsPage extends StatelessWidget {
    final List<Quotes> quote = Httpservice.quoteOfTheDay;

    PostsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("quotes"),
   ),
   body: FutureBuilder(
    //future: httpService.getQuotes(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Quotes>> 
    snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        //Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        // Quote? quotes = snapshot.data;
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('" ${quote[0].quote} ?? '' "');
        }
        return Text('" ${quote[0].quote} ?? '' "');
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: const [
            SizedBox(height: 400.0),
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Text('loading')
          ]),
         );
       }
      },
     ),
   );
  }
 }
```

This is the model data

```
       class Quotes {
       String? quote;
       String? length;
       String? author;
       List<String>? tags;
       String? category;
      String? language;
      String? date;
      String? permalink;
      String? id;
      String? background;
      String? title;

     Quotes(
    {this.quote,
    this.length,
    this.author,
    this.tags,
    this.category,
    this.language,
    this.date,
    this.permalink,
    this.id,
    this.background,
    this.title});

   Quotes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   quote = json['quote'];
   length = json['length'];
   author = json['author'];
   tags = json['tags'].cast<String>();
   category = json['category'];
   language = json['language'];
   date = json['date'];
   permalink = json['permalink'];
   id = json['id'];
   background = json['background'];
   title = json['title'];
   }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
  data['quote'] = quote;
  data['length'] = length;
  data['author'] = author;
  data['tags'] = tags;
 data['category'] = category;
 data['language'] = language;
 data['date'] = date;
 data['permalink'] = permalink;
 data['id'] = id;
 data['background'] = background;
 data['title'] = title;
 return data;
 }
}
```

Model data 2

```
 import 'quotes.dart';

 class Contents {
 List<Quotes>? quotes;

 Contents({this.quotes});

Contents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
if (json['quotes']) {
  quotes = <Quotes>[];
  json['quotes'].forEach((v) {
    quotes!.add(Quotes.fromJson(v));
  });
  }
 }

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
if (quotes != null) {
  data['quotes'] = quotes!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
  }
 return data;
   }
  }
```

This is the code to all the major pages. when i try to display the quote from the class Quote nothing shows. i continously keep on getting this error when i try to navigate to the display page.Another exception was thrown: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List'
i really dont know what im doing wrong and im slumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using FutureBuilder to get data. Snapshot that is returned does have List, however you are getting quoteOfTheDay before FutureBuilder which is null. Best way is to get data, when it is loaded,is through snapshot.
Here is the working code:

PostsPage:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'http_service.dart';
import 'model_quote.dart';

class PostsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  PostsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("quotes"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Httpservice().getQuotes(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Quotes>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
            // Quote? quotes = snapshot.data;
            final List<Quotes> quotes = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: quotes.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  return Container(
                      child: Text('" ${quotes[0].quote} ?? ' ' "'));
                });
          } else {
            return Column(children: const [
              SizedBox(height: 400.0),
              Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Text('loading')
            ]);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HTTP Service

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'model_quote.dart';

class Httpservice {
  final Uri postURL = Uri.parse(
    "https://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire",
  );

  Future<List<Quotes>> getQuotes() async {
    Response res = await get(postURL);
    final jsonItems = json.decode(res.body)["contents"]["quotes"];
    List<Quotes> quote = jsonItems.map<Quotes>((json) {
      print(json);
      return Quotes.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();
    return quote;
  }
}
```

Comment: i just tried it and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in this line `final List<Quotes> quote = Httpservice.quoteOfTheDay;`. As the variable `quote` is expecting `List<Quotes>` and you are calling `Httpservice.quoteOfTheDay` which is returning a null value.

Instead, you should call `Httpservice.getQuotes()`, as this method is returning the expected value.

```
final List<Quotes> quote = Httpservice.getQuotes();
```